# How to access cobertura line coverage in a groovy script during Jenkins run

Tags: cobertura

I'm trying to setup a jenkins job with a groovy post build script where I need to get line coverage generated using cobertura

```
percentage = build.getAction(hudson.plugins.cobertura.CoberturaBuildAction.class).getLineCoverage().getPercentageFloat();

groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: hudson.plugins.cobertura.CoberturaBuildAction.getLineCoverage() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:55)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:46)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
at Script1.coverage(Script1.groovy:5)
at Script1$coverage.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:19)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:580)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:618)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:589)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SecureGroovyScript.evaluate(SecureGroovyScript.java:166)
at org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.groovypostbuild.GroovyPostbuildRecorder.perform(GroovyPostbuildRecorder.java:362)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:772)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:736)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1040)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:685)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1757)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:529)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:234)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
import hudson.plugins.cobertura.targets.CoverageMetric;

percentage = build.getAction(hudson.plugins.cobertura.CoberturaBuildAction.class).getResults()[CoverageMetric.LINE].getPercentageFloat();
```